# Not able to display repeater elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

using protractor I am testing a Angular JS application :

I have a search function in my application, after automating the navigation part to trigger a search request. I am trying to extract my search results with this code :

```
element.all(by.repeater('object in objects')).then(function (arr){
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
        arr[i].getText().then(function(text){
            console.log('item:'+i+text);
        });
```

Here is my console output :

```
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
item:20TSK(ACE700J)(000)(ACE700JU00)(000) upd tsk label
item:20TSK(BEN705JU39)(000)
item:20TSK(IAM710JUW5)(000)
item:20TSK(CDF010JD00)(000)
item:20TSK(IAL755JFZZ)(000)
item:20TSK(IAQ781JU70)(000)
item:20
item:20
item:20
item:20
item:20
item:20
item:20
item:20
item:20
item:20
item:20
item:20
item:20
item:20
.
Finished in 13.893 seconds
1 test, 0 assertions, 0 failures
```

So in fact I am facing two issue :

1. Why 'i' is always 20?
2. Why I am only able to extract 6 out of 20 items whereas I can see
   that 20 items are well displayed in the screen?

Here is the structure of my search results :

```
<div id="mainViewNav">
<div id="sortByBand">
    <div id="jobHolder" class="thumbJobs" style="height: 63px; overflow: hidden;" tabindex="5017">
        <div id="job_1" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
            <div id="job_1_viewerEye" class="viewerEye" ng-click="viewerEye($event,$index+1, object)" ng-class="object.viewerEyeClass"></div>
            <div id="job_1_jobBigPicto" class="jobBigPicto transition_2_opa">
                <img class="jobBigImg" title="07" onerror="this.src = 'images/icons/search_results/application_types/application_default.png'" alt="" ng-src="images/icons/search_results/application_types/application_default.png" src="images/icons/search_results/application_types/application_default.png">
                <img class="jobLaunchMethod" title="Scheduled" alt="" ng-src="images/icons/search_results/task_types/scheduled.png" src="images/icons/search_results/task_types/scheduled.png">
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="job_1_jobsSmallPictos" class="jobsSmallPictos transition_2_opa">
                <img class="jobsSmallImg ng-scope" ng-repeat="jobType in object.uprocTypes" title="CMD" alt="" ng-src="images/icons/search_results/uproc_types/CMD.png" src="images/icons/search_results/uproc_types/CMD.png">
            </div>
            <div id="job_1_jobDown" class="jobDown transition_2_opa">
                <div class="jobTitle ng-binding">TSK(ACE700J)(000)(ACE700JU00)(000)</div>
                <div class="jobText ng-binding">upd tsk label</div>
            </div>
            <div id="job_1_jobHoverInfo" class="jobHoverInfo" ng-click="hideJobHoverInfo($event,$index+1)">
                <div class="jobInfoNameBlock">
                    <div class="jobInfoContextBlock">
                        <div class="jobDetailsBtn ng-binding" ng-click="viewWorkflow(object)">View details...</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="job_2" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                    <div id="job_2_viewerEye" class="viewerEye" ng-click="viewerEye($event,$index+1, object)" ng-class="object.viewerEyeClass"></div>
                    <div id="job_2_jobBigPicto" class="jobBigPicto transition_2_opa">
                        <div id="job_2_jobsSmallPictos" class="jobsSmallPictos transition_2_opa">
                            <div id="job_2_jobDown" class="jobDown transition_2_opa">
                                <div id="job_2_jobHoverInfo" class="jobHoverInfo" ng-click="hideJobHoverInfo($event,$index+1)">
                                </div>
                                <div id="job_3" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                    <div id="job_3_viewerEye" class="viewerEye" ng-click="viewerEye($event,$index+1, object)" ng-class="object.viewerEyeClass"></div>
                                    <div id="job_3_jobBigPicto" class="jobBigPicto transition_2_opa">
                                        <div id="job_3_jobsSmallPictos" class="jobsSmallPictos transition_2_opa">
                                            <div id="job_3_jobDown" class="jobDown transition_2_opa">
                                                <div id="job_3_jobHoverInfo" class="jobHoverInfo" ng-click="hideJobHoverInfo($event,$index+1)">
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="job_4" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                                    <div id="job_5" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                                        <div id="job_6" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                                            <div id="job_7" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                                                <div id="job_8" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                                                    <div id="job_9" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                                                        <div id="job_10" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                                                            <div id="job_11" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                                                                <div id="job_12" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                                                                    <div id="job_13" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                                                                        <div id="job_14" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                                                                            <div id="job_15" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                                                                                <div id="job_16" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                                                                                    <div id="job_17" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                                                                                        <div id="job_18" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                                                                                            <div id="job_19" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                                                                                                <div id="job_20" class="job ng-scope" ng-click="showJobHoverInfo($index+1)" ng-repeat="object in objects" ng-class="object.jobStyle">
                                                                                                                </div>
                                                                                                                </section>
```

Thanks for your answer I have downloaded async library my code now looks like this :

```
describe('search', function () {

var ptor;
var Q = require("C:/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q");
var async = require("C:/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/async");
beforeEach(function ()

    {
        ptor = protractor.getInstance();
        ptor.get('http://frstmwarwebsrv2.orsyptst.com:9000/');
        //Delete cookies to avoid saving password or username
        ptor.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    });

it('extract data', function ()

    {
        element(by.id('login_form_user_input')).sendKeys('user_001_X');
        element(by.id('login_form_password_input')).sendKeys('admin');
        element(by.id('login_form_signin_button')).click()
        element(by.id('mainGlobalSearch')).sendKeys('tsk');
        element(by.id('mainGlobalSearchBtn')).click()

        element.all(by.repeater('object in objects')).then(function (arr)


            {

                var resultArray = [];
                async.eachSeries(arr, function (element)

                    {
                        element.getText().then(function (text, cb)

                            {
                                resultArray.push(text);
                                cb(null);
                            });
                    },

                    function (err)

                    {
                        console.log(resultArray.join(' '));
                        // continue testing
                    });
            });

    });



 });
```

However I am getting this error :

```
Failures:

 1) search extract data
 Message:
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
 Stacktrace:
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
 at C:\Users\orsyp\DUX\k_workload_ar\ui\e2e\searchbyall.spec.js:38:21
at C:\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.

Finished in 11.534 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that getText is asynchronous.

The fastest fix would be to use [async eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries)

A quick untested example on how to use `eachSeries` for your case :

```
var resultArray = [];
async.eachSeries(arr, function(element) {
  element.getText().then(function (text, cb) {
    resultArray.push(text);
    cb(null);
  });
}, function (err) {
  console.log(resultArray.join(' ');
  // continue testing
});
```